# Why data in table calculating twicely whenever row is deleted

Tags: jquery, html-table, calculated-columns, delete-row

[simple pos system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmmNC.png)
I am working in a basic pos system and I do want to delete order items from the order details table which is having ("item code, description, unitprice, qty, total").
The problem is when I delete my row, the total is subtracting twice from the subtotal and giving the wrong calculation. I do not understand why it is working like that.
If anyone can help with this problem really appreciated it.
Thank you.

Here is my code..

Html Code-

```
 <div id="tblContainer" class="table-dark">
                    <table id="tblOrderDetails" class="table table-hover table-dark">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="text-center">Item Code</th>
                                <th>Description</th>
                                <th>Unit Price</th>
                                <th class="text-center">Qty</th>
                                <th class="text-right">Total</th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="orderdetailsbody">
                        
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span id="spnTotal">Total: <label id="lblTotal">0.0</label></span>
                    <button id="btnPlaceOrder" class="btn btn-primary"> <i class="fas fa-cart-arrow-down"></i>
                        Place Order</button>
                </div>
```

$("#tblOrderDetails tr td:last-child div").click(function(){

```
            var deleteQty = parseInt($(this).parent().parent().find("td:nth-child(4)").text());
            var deleteItem = $(this).parent().parent().find("td:first-child").text();
            
            for(i=0; i<ITEMS.length;i++){
                if(deleteItem == ITEMS[i].code){
                    ITEMS[i].qtyOnHand += deleteQty; 
                }
            }
            var newTotal = 0;
            var subTotal = parseFloat($("#lblTotal").text());
            var rowTotal = parseFloat($(this).parent().parent().find("td:nth-child(5)").text());
            newTotal = subTotal - rowTotal;
            $("#lblTotal").text(newTotal);

            $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut(500);
            var row = $(this).parent().parent();
            setTimeout(function(){
                row.remove();
            },600);

           });
```

Comment: show html code as well

Comment: Html code is updated, Thank you

Comment: still missing content inside `orderdetailsbody` .

Comment: I am giving dynamic data from the user interface. I have uploaded an image of my interface (in the starting "simple pos system"). Please check it

Comment: are you seeing that behaviour [here](https://jsfiddle.net/97woku4x/) as well ?

Comment: Yes, It's giving the wrong calculation there as well, In here it's update the quantity twice.

Comment: where in total or quantity ?

Comment: In total it is subtracting twice and in quantity, it is adding twice